# Select the latest event with a distinct 2 columns in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with a schema like so:

```
{
  {"name": "timeCreated", "type": "datetime"},
  {"name": "userid", "type": "string"},
  {"name": "textid", "type": "string"},
  {"name": "textvalue": "type": "float"}
}
```

I am trying to make a query so I end up with the row of the latest timeCreated for each pair of userid and textid combinations. I have tried GROUP BY et al but I cannot seem to get the ORDER BY the timeCreated field then remove all the rows that are not at the top for each pair of userid and textid columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the latest(last) or earliest(first) element of a group in Google BigQuery you can use [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) with [[OFFSET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#offset_and_ordinal)(0)] and appropriate ORDER BY (DESC or ASC):

```
WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT DATETIME '2020-11-01 01:00:00' AS timeCreated, 'user1' AS userid, 'text1' AS textid, 1.1 AS textvalue UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2020-11-01 03:00:00' AS timeCreated, 'user1' AS userid, 'text1' AS textid, 1.2 AS textvalue UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2020-11-01 02:00:00' AS timeCreated, 'user1' AS userid, 'text1' AS textid, 1.3 AS textvalue UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2020-11-01 02:00:00' AS timeCreated, 'user1' AS userid, 'text2' AS textid, 1.4 AS textvalue UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2020-11-01 01:00:00' AS timeCreated, 'user1' AS userid, 'text2' AS textid, 1.5 AS textvalue UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AS timeCreated, 'user2' AS userid, 'text1' AS textid, 1.6 AS textvalue
)
SELECT 
  userid,
  textid,
  ARRAY_AGG(timeCreated ORDER BY timeCreated DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS latest FROM test_table
GROUP BY userid, textid
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select as value array_agg(t order by timeCreated desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by userid, textid
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, you can use MAX instead of ARRAY_AGG.

```
SELECT 
  userid,
  textid,
  MAX(timeCreated) AS latest
FROM test_table
GROUP BY userid, textid
```